# Vue.js - How to Avoid Code Duplication

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How does one avoid code duplication when using something like computed properties across multiple components?

An example is that I have a computed property to get the parent route name - it's pretty simple:

```
computed: {
  parent_route () {
    return this.$route.matched[0].name
  }
}
```

I am finding that I use this computed property across multiple components.  How could I store this in one place that all my components can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Mixins**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). For the most general case there's the [**Global Mixin**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) (use with care):

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
      parent_route () {
        return this.$route.matched[0].name
      }
    }
})
```

The `this.parent_route` computed property is now automatically defined in ***all*** components.

But you should avoid abusing global mixins. Instead, you can apply them locally using [**Option Merging**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging) (the `mixins` option):

```
var mixin = {
    computed: {
      parent_route () {
        return this.$route.matched[0].name
      }
    }
};

new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: function () {},
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.parent_route) // should be ok
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks - can't believed I missed this in the docs.  Would using Vuex be an alternative to this approach?

Comment: If you are talking about data only, then yes, Vuex is the way. That `parent_route` of yours, though, couldn't be used in Vuex, because it is not data, you'd have to insert it into the store, but even if you did, the data is relative (each component has a `parent_route`, not one for all), so it would get a bit less useful. But if all you want to share is data, definitely go Vuex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixins. Create myMixin.js file with:

```
export const myMixin = {
 computed: {
  parent_route () {
    return this.$route.matched[0].name
  }
 }
}
```

Then you can import it in your vue component like this:

import {myMixin} from '../myMixin.js' //valid path to myMixin.js file here

and register it:

```
...
data {...},
mixins: [myMixin],
methods: {...}
...
```

More on mixins:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html